# Deformation invariance of Fano varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, fano-varieties

Let $f:X \to T$ be a flat, projective morphism of noetherian schemes with $T$ an irreducible curve. Suppose that there exists a point $0 \in T$ such that  the fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ is Fano.

> **Q.** Is it true that in this case, for all $t$ near $0$, the fiber $f^{-1}(t)$ is Fano?

N.B. If necessary, one can assume that $f$ is smooth, but if such a statement holds without this assumption, it would be more interesting.

Comment: It is definitely asking too much for this to hold for _all_ $t \in C$. Even if $f$ is smooth, this will typically only hold for $t$ near 0.

Comment: @potentiallydense Thanks. Could you give a reference for your second statement.

Comment: To add to what @potentially dense was saying: Take $X_t$ to be a family of blow-ups of $P^2$ in three points for instance. For a general choice of three points, this is Del Pezzo, but it is not when the points are colinear. In general you get that there is a nbh where $X_t$ is Fano. This follows because ampleness of -K is an open property in families.

Comment: @gbp , potentiallydense, thank you. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, in fact the following result holds.

> **Theorem.** Let $f \colon X \to T$ be a flat deformation of a Fano variety $X_0:=f^{-1}(0)$ having at most terminal, $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial singularities.
>
> Then $X_t:=f^{-1}(t)$ is a Fano variety with at most terminal, $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial singularities, for all $t$ in a neighborhood of $0$ in $T$.

For a proof, see Corollary 3.2 and Proposition 3.8 in

*De Fernex, Tommaso; Hacon, Christopher D.*, [**Deformations of canonical pairs and Fano varieties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/CRELLE.2011.010), J. Reine Angew. Math. **651**, 97-126 (2011). [ZBL1220.14026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1220.14026).